# Want to change collective select option based on above select option

Tags: laravel

I have three laravel select drop down menu in which I want filter each one base on above selection

here is my code

```
{!!Form::label('Exam', 'exam') !!}

{{ Form::select('exam', $exam, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}  

{!!Form::label('Standard', 'standard') !!}

{{ Form::select('standard', $standard, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}  

{!!Form::label('Student', 'student') !!}

{{ Form::select('student', $student ,null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}
```

Comment: show me your controller??

Comment: public function create()
    {
        $data['exam']=Exams::pluck('exam', 'id')->toArray();
        $data['standard']=Standard::pluck('class_name', 'id')->toArray();
        $data['student']=Students::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
        return view('students.results.create',$data);
    }